# Insert value from XML to Mysql table using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I am able to view the xml file using xmlDocument property in c#. But i want to know how can I insert the xml file value into Mysql database table. My table structure will be like: 
iEmpID int, 
vEname varchar,
iSalary int,
cEdept char.

this is the xml file to be inserted in that above table using c# WPF

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <employee>
    <iEmpId>20</iEmpId>
    <vEname>Viky</vEname>
    <iSalary>30000</iSalary>
    <cEdept>Testing</cEdept>
 </employee>
```

can any one give some suggestions?

Comment: Does the file contain one or more employee elements? If it contains multiple `employee` elements without a root element, it is malformed and will require special handling during deserialization

Comment: Also, what `XmlDocument` property are you talking about? Is the data already loaded in a DataTable, DataSet, XmlDataDocument or just plain XmlDocument? In this case all you need is to execute the proper ADO.NET commands